# NotFittedError: This MultinomialNB instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a spam classifier using 4 different algorithms, it is written in python , the code goes something like this :

```
#4. Model Building
#----------------------
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer,TfidfVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=3000)

X = tfidf.fit_transform(df['transformed_text']).toarray()

#from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
#scaler = MinMaxScaler()
#X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
# appending the num_character col to X
#X = np.hstack((X,df['num_characters'].values.reshape(-1,1)))

X.shape

y = df['target'].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=2)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB,MultinomialNB,BernoulliNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,confusion_matrix,precision_score

gnb = GaussianNB()
mnb = MultinomialNB()
bnb = BernoulliNB()

gnb.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred1 = gnb.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred1))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred1))
print(precision_score(y_test,y_pred1))

mnb.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred2 = mnb.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred2))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred2))
print(precision_score(y_test,y_pred2))

bnb.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred3 = bnb.predict(X_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred3))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred3))
print(precision_score(y_test,y_pred3))


from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

svc = SVC(kernel='sigmoid', gamma=1.0)
knc = KNeighborsClassifier()
mnb = MultinomialNB()
dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5)


clfs = {
    'SVC' : svc,
    'KN' : knc, 
    'NB': mnb, 
    'DT': dtc, 

}

def train_classifier(clf,X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test):
    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
    precision = precision_score(y_test,y_pred)
    
    return accuracy,precision

train_classifier(svc,X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test)

accuracy_scores = []
precision_scores = []

for name,clf in clfs.items():
    
    current_accuracy,current_precision = train_classifier(clf, X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test)
    
    print("For ",name)
    print("Accuracy - ",current_accuracy)
    print("Precision - ",current_precision)
    
    accuracy_scores.append(current_accuracy)
    precision_scores.append(current_precision)
    
performance_df = pd.DataFrame({'Algorithm':clfs.keys(),'Accuracy':accuracy_scores,'Precision':precision_scores}).sort_values('Precision',ascending=False)

performance_df

performance_df1 = pd.melt(performance_df, id_vars = "Algorithm")
performance_df1

sns.catplot(x = 'Algorithm', y='value', 
               hue = 'variable',data=performance_df1, kind='bar',height=5)
plt.ylim(0.5,1.0)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.show()

# model improve
# 1. Change the max_features parameter of TfIdf
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Algorithm':clfs.keys(),'Accuracy_max_ft_3000':accuracy_scores,'Precision_max_ft_3000':precision_scores}).sort_values('Precision_max_ft_3000',ascending=False)
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Algorithm':clfs.keys(),'Accuracy_scaling':accuracy_scores,'Precision_scaling':precision_scores}).sort_values('Precision_scaling',ascending=False)
new_df = performance_df.merge(temp_df,on='Algorithm')
new_df_scaled = new_df.merge(temp_df,on='Algorithm')
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Algorithm':clfs.keys(),'Accuracy_num_chars':accuracy_scores,'Precision_num_chars':precision_scores}).sort_values('Precision_num_chars',ascending=False)
new_df_scaled.merge(temp_df,on='Algorithm')

# Voting Classifier
svc = SVC(kernel='sigmoid', gamma=1.0,probability=True)
mnb = MultinomialNB()
etc = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=50, random_state=2)

from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
voting = VotingClassifier(estimators=[('svm', svc), ('nb', mnb)],voting='soft')
voting.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = voting.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy",accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
print("Precision",precision_score(y_test,y_pred))

# Applying stacking
estimators=[('svm', svc), ('nb', mnb),('et', etc)]
final_estimator=RandomForestClassifier()
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
clf = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators, final_estimator=final_estimator)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy",accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
print("Precision",precision_score(y_test,y_pred))

import pickle
pickle.dump(tfidf,open('vectorizer.pkl','wb'))
pickle.dump(mnb,open('model.pkl','wb'))
```

I am using pycharm virtual environment to create web interface for the spam classifier it goes like this

```
import streamlit as st
import pickle
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

ps = PorterStemmer()


def transform_text(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

    y = []
    for i in text:
        if i.isalnum():
            y.append(i)

    text = y[:]
    y.clear()

    for i in text:
        if i not in stopwords.words('english') and i not in string.punctuation:
            y.append(i)

    text = y[:]
    y.clear()

    for i in text:
        y.append(ps.stem(i))

    return " ".join(y)


tfidf = pickle.load(open('vectorizer.pkl', 'rb'))
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

st.title("Email/SMS Spam Classifier")

input_sms = st.text_area("Enter the message")

if st.button('Predict'):

    # 1. preprocess
    transformed_sms = transform_text(input_sms)
    # 2. vectorize
    vector_input = tfidf.transform([transformed_sms])
    # 3. predict
    result = model.predict(vector_input)[0]
    # 4. Display
    if result == 1:
        st.header("Spam")
    else:
        st.header("Not Spam")
```

On running the app using streamlit run app.py the the code runs and displays content on local host but on entering value into text input and presing predict we get the following error:

```
NotFittedError: This MultinomialNB instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\dhair\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 443, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\dhair\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\app.py", line 50, in <module>
    result = model.predict(vector_input)[0]
File "C:\Users\dhair\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 81, in predict
    check_is_fitted(self)
File "C:\Users\dhair\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 1222, in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {"name": type(estimator).__name__})
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Now the error is resolved , what happened was that I forgot to fit the mnb statement

```
mnb.fit(X_train,y_train)
```